# How do I properly structure code repository for multi tenancy?

Tags: terraform

I have terraform code which need to deploy resources in Azure for a company. There are some shared resources (like SQL server for example `sql-server`) and there are some resources which are client specific (for example SQL DB `client1-DB`, client specific subnet `client1-subnet` etc). My plan was to have every client to have their own `clientX.tfvar` file with client specific information and then execute `apply` with specifying `-var-file` argument.
Question wether it's best approach? That is, if just having one big `allclients.tfvar` might be better instead.
What I'm uncertain of is how do I properly use TerraformCloud if I keep each current and future client variables in separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Approach documented here solves this dilemma
https://dev.to/piotrgwiazda/main-module-approach-for-handling-multiple-environments-in-terraform-1oln